# Regex which does not allow leading space and any character from (^\\/:*?"<>|)

Tags: regex

I have a regex like "`^[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\+[^\\/:*?"<>|]+)*([\\\\]+)?$`" which is responsible for file path validation.

It successfully validates paths like `C:\Users\data` and `C:\\Users\\data`

I want the string which comes after "`C:\`" to not start with space and not have `(^\\/:*?"<>|)` characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use match the start of the string up till the colon and use your negated character class to not match your unwanted characters right after. You could add a space or `\s` to  that character class to not match that as well.

Also you might use a capturing group and  backreference to which variant is used for the backslashed `\\` or `\`

After that you could use a repeating pattern and specify which characters to allow for the rest of the string.

```
^[a-zA-Z]:(\\+)(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|\s][\w&]+(?: [\w&]+)*(?:\1[a-zA-Z&]+)*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/af4ijz/1)

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]:` - `[a-zA-Z]:` Match a-zA-Z and a colon
- `(\\+)` Capture in a group 1+ times a backslash to reference it
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^\\/:*?"<>|\s]` Negated character class to not match 1+ times what is listed (Added `\s` but you could also just use a space)
  - `[\w&]+(?: [\w&]+)*` Match 1+ times a word char and repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ times a word char. Note that you can extend the character class to match what you want.
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\1[a-zA-Z&]+` Match backreference to what is captured in group 1 followed by 1+ times a-zA-Z (You can add to the character class what you would like to match as well)
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat it 0+ times
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of the string

Comment: But this solution does not allow a valid entry like "C:\" and "C:\\Users data\\data\\test"

Comment: It does not match "C:\\Users\\d&ata\\test\\". I want C:\\any word here except [^\\/:*?"<>|] and it cannot start with space and can have space anywhere else\\ (it may or may not end with \\or\)

Comment: @J.Doe You can turn the `\w+` into a character class and add what you would allow to match like https://regex101.com/r/UeC7tK/2

Comment: @J.Doe I have updated the answer. If you would not allow only a single backslash between the backslashes that separates the directories, you could might shorten the regex to `^[a-zA-Z]:(\\+)(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|\s][^\\\n]+(?:\1[^\\\n]+)*)?$` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIpTom/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1)

> Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else. When explaining character classes, this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a q not followed by a u. Negative lookahead provides the solution: q(?!u)

So you can mix it with if-then-else regex statement like `(?(?!your_pattern_in_regex)match_then|match_else)`